# Oracle doesn't sort properly when using the same column twice

Tags: database, oracle, sorting, date

When I run this query, results aren't sorted correctly.

```
SELECT 
  SYSDATE - datecolumn a,
  SYSDATE - datecolumn sortcolumn
FROM atable
ORDER BY sortcolumn
```

Produces:

```
2576.780243055555555555555555555555555556
2586.297013888888888888888888888888888889
2342.294479166666666666666666666666666667
2617.297476851851851851851851851851851852
2624.855104166666666666666666666666666667
2624.855138888888888888888888888888888889
2624.854236111111111111111111111111111111
2372.296643518518518518518518518518518519
2645.257800925925925925925925925925925926
2403.294756944444444444444444444444444444
2676.297696759259259259259259259259259259
```

When the first line (SYSDATE - datecolumn a,) is removed, everything works fine. Is there any particular reason why this is happening?

Comment: Try `TO_NUMBER(SYSDATE - datecolumn) as sort_column` . I presume the sort with your SQL is not numeric.

Comment: Interesting behavior (I can confirm it on Oracle 11gR2). There are many workarounds but it would be nice to know whether it's a bug or a feature.

Comment: on my instaince all work as expected, try to rebuild your table (I faced with oracle issues when table is corrupted) or provide full test case (with table creation and filling)

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a bug. This behaviour looks similar to bug 8675087, which is supposedly fixed in 11.2.0.2 - and indeed I can't reproduce the test case for that. But I still see your behaviour in that version (on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/29596)) and in 11.2.0.3, so this is similar but not exactly the same...

If this is causing you a real issue and you can't find a workaround you're happy with (like swapping the column order; if your `sortcolumn` is the first expression that uses `sysdate` it seems to be OK, but swapping columns in your real query might not be convenient) then you should raise a service request with Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Fascinating bug. Reproduced on 11.2.0.2.

Even happens if the query is wrapped in a subquery:

```
select * from (
  select sysdate - db_created_on a
        ,sysdate - db_created_on b
  from members
) order by b;
```

(results not sorted correctly)

```
select * from (
  select sysdate - db_created_on a
        ,sysdate - db_created_on b
  from members
) order by a;
```

(results sorted correctly)

The best workaround I can think of is to use a scalar subquery for SYSDATE, this seems to cause it to sort correctly:

```
select sysdate - db_created_on a
      ,(select sysdate from dual) - db_created_on b
from members
order by b;
```